# How to Randomly Set Initial Index Declaratively or in Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList and want to randomly set the selected index at PageLoad.
Can this be done declaratively in the aspx file?

If so, how? If not, how do I do so in PageLoad() in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no idea how to do this in the aspx... but on PageLoad you just do this:

```
myDropDownList.SelectedIndex = new System.Random().Next (myDropDownList.Items.Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

It s possible...

You may use the following code lines in `Page_Load` event's event handler:

```
Random r = new Random();
int nextIndex = r.Next(0, dropDownList1.Items.Count);
dropDownList1.SelectedIndex = nextIndex;
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

On aspx you would have you use a script.  Just do it on PageLoad, seems cleaner.

Javascript code is this:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlList');
ddl.options[Math.floor(Math.random()*(ddl.options.length+1))].selected = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SN47U/

Answer (score 1):

No, its possible only in Page_Load

```
        var rnd = new Random();
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = rnd.Next(listBox1.Items.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = new Random().Next(0,DropDownList1.Items.Count);
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```